# Why does AdjustTokenPrivileges not work here?

Tags: winapi

I just wanted to write a little application to flush the filesystem-cache with Windows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

DWORD SetPrivilege( HANDLE hToken, LPCWSTR lpszPrivilege, bool enablePrivilege );

int wmain( int argc, wchar_t **argv )
{
    if( argc >= 4 )
    {
        HANDLE hUserToken;
        if( !LogonUserW( argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hUserToken ) )
            return (cout << "wrong credentialds" << endl), EXIT_FAILURE;
        if( !ImpersonateLoggedOnUser( hUserToken ) )
            return (cout << "wrong can't impersonate user" << endl), EXIT_FAILURE;
        if( SetPrivilege( hUserToken, L"SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", true ) != NO_ERROR )
            return (cout << "can't assign privolege" << endl), EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if( !SetSystemFileCacheSize( -1, -1, 0 ) )
        return (cout << "flushing failed " << GetLastError() << endl), EXIT_FAILURE;
}

DWORD SetPrivilege( HANDLE hToken, LPCWSTR lpszPrivilege, bool enablePrivilege )
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID             privilegeLuid;
    if( !LookupPrivilegeValueW( nullptr, lpszPrivilege, &privilegeLuid ) )
        return GetLastError();
    tp.PrivilegeCount           = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid       = privilegeLuid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = enablePrivilege ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;
    if( !AdjustTokenPrivileges( hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof tp, nullptr, nullptr ) )
        return GetLastError();
    if( GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED )
        return ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED;
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Unfortunately AdjustTokenPrivileges doesn't work and GetLastError() returns ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED  even if I log in as Administrator. How could I fix this ?

Comment: Have you run your program with an elevated token and not just as Administrator? (Change your manifest to require elevated to give that a try)

Comment: *hUserToken* simply not have *SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege* as result *AdjustTokenPrivileges* fail. *AdjustTokenPrivileges* not add privilege to token. this api on or off existing in token privilege. as side note - call *SetPrivilege* after *ImpersonateLoggedOnUser* will have no effect on thread token. and you not close *hUserToken*

Comment: @SoronelHaetir - in code used token from *LogonUserW*, but not from current process.

Comment: You can't grant yourself privileges that you don't already have. As RbMm said, `hUserToken` does not have `SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege`. You need to use a token with this privilege to enable it.